# Android : equals between pictures text

Tags: java, android, database, imageview, equals

iam working on some android app right now and i want to check if the button i clicked on(the text inside him) is equals to the Imageview(the image iam showing)text. (if the flag tahat in the picture is equale to the text in the answer button)and i have a problem
//the notes are in hebrew sorry
the line f = db.getFlag(num);//is for getting an a random flag from the dataHandler

in the answer1 onclick i have the problem its says:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable f inside an inner class defined in a different method

code:

```
package com.example.flagsgame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ClassicMode extends Activity {//מהמשחק עצמו

String pic;
Button answer1;
Button answer2;
Button answer3;
Button answer4;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);



    answer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    answer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    answer3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    answer4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Flags f = new Flags();
    Random r = new Random();//הדגל שיבחר לשאלה
    int num = r.nextInt(70);//Up
    Log.d("yes", "yes");
    //Random ra = new Random();//הדגלים שיהיו בתשובות
    //int numA = ra.nextInt(4);//Up

    f = db.getFlag(num);//הצגת הדגל הרנדומלי שיצא
//  final Flags d = f; // trying to make it final but it dosent help
    pic = f.getImage().toString();
    pic_view(pic);//מעבר לפונקציה להשמת התמונה של הדגל במשחק
    //מערך ארבע כפתורים כנגד ארבע תשובות
    Button [] b = new Button[4];
    b[0] = answer1; 
    b[1] = answer2;
    b[2] = answer3;
    b[3] = answer4;

    List<String>Answers=new ArrayList<String>();//מערך תשובות
    Answers.add(f.getName().toString());//הוספת התשובה הנכונה
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());//הוספת 3 תשובות רנדומליות
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());

    Collections.shuffle(Answers);//ערבוב התשובות

    for(int i=0;i<Answers.size();i++)
    {
        b[i].setText(Answers.get(i));//השמת התשובות מהמהערך למערך הכפתורים
    }

    answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(answer1.getText().toString().equals(f.getName().toString()))
            {
                resetQuiz();
            }
            //else
                //guess--...

        }
    });
    //answer2.setOnClickListener(myHandler2);
    //answer3.setOnClickListener(myHandler3);
    //answer4.setOnClickListener(myHandler4);


}//end of OnCreat


public void resetQuiz()
{
        }

/*View.OnClickListener myHandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

View.OnClickListener myHandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

View.OnClickListener myHandler4 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

private void pic_view(String pic2) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //גישה לדגל לפי שמו וייבוא התמונה
    Log.d("Result from pic function " , pic2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    String uri ="@drawable/";
    uri += pic2;
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, pic2, getPackageName());//הצוות התמונה 
    Drawable res= getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);//ציור התמונה
    imageView.setImageDrawable(res);

}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean?switch for all the button ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making f final?
You can change your f instantiation to look as follows:

```
final Flags f = new Flags();
```

Comment: yes ive tried i made it there as a note because it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as final, but I'll try a different solution like using onclick as an intermediate method. Something like this:

```
answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        check((Button) v);
    }
});

void check(Button clicked) {
    if(clicked.getText().toString().equals(f.getName().toString())) {
        resetQuiz();
    }
    //else
    //guess--...        
}
```

EDITED: Move f variable to class member scope:

```
...
Button answer3;
Button answer4;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
Flags f = new Flags();
```

Also, I'd consider a way to link buttons and images instead of using the flags object. Looks odd to me. But that's a different thing.

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable f inside an inner class defined in a different method same error

Comment: ok but i didnt get it i did what you sayed in the ClassicMode class you want me to make a new class and there i shpuld declare the f?and then the classic mode will extends?

Comment: There's no need todo do that, just move that variable from local scope to class. I tried to point that showing where you declare it along the other members.

Answer (score 0):

The "Flags f = new Flags();" statement could be moved to the line immediately below "DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);". otoh, I might have also considered extending the button to accept Flags f in it's constructor. Depends on the rest of the code

Comment: what do you mean by extednding the button to accept Flgas f?

Comment: `public class MyButton extends Button { Context c; Flags f; public MyButton(Context c, Flags f) { this.context = context; this.f = f } onClickListener(...) { whatever.equals(f.getName().toString()) } }`